# When using the lockable module in the Devise gem in Ruby on Rails, why is my failed_attempts field not increasing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

When using the lockable module in Devise, why is the `failed_attempts` field not increasing? Is there something wrong with my setup? `failed_attempts` does not move from 0 when a login fails with a bad password.

**routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations' }
devise_for :admins, controllers: { registrations: 'admins/registrations' }, skip: [:sessions]
```

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "admins", :force => true do |t|
    ...
    t.integer  "failed_attempts",                       :default => 0
    t.string   "unlock_token"
    t.datetime "locked_at"
    ...
end

create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    ...
    t.integer  "failed_attempts",                                  :default => 0
    t.string   "unlock_token"
    t.datetime "locked_at"
    ...
end
```

**user.rb**

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :token_authenticatable, :lockable, remember_for: 4.weeks
```

**admin.rb**

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :trackable, :validatable, :lockable, :timeoutable, timeout_in: 60.minutes
```

**devise.rb**

```
config.lock_strategy = :failed_attempts
config.unlock_keys = [ :email ]
config.unlock_strategy = :both
config.maximum_attempts = 3
config.unlock_in = 1.hour
```

**Versions**

```
Rails 3.2.0
Ruby 1.9.3p194
Devise 2.1.2
```

Comment: The config looks good. Could you add the log details when there is a failed attempt? Specifically, the log should show an sql query to update the `failed_attempts` field for that user. Or give some indication as to why it is not doing that.

Comment: similar problem to me. Can u suggest me what have you done for this?